# How to get total sum of all column in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

> My query in my controller

```
 public function show($id)
    {
       $structural = DB::table('attendance')->where('payroll_daily_id',$id)
       ->where('assignment','STRUCTURAL')
       ->select('payroll_daily_attendance.*')
       ->get();

       $fetch = [];
       foreach($structural as $key){
            if(!isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_ot']) && !isset($fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days']) ){
               $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_ot'] = 0;
               $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days'] = 0;
             }
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['wrk_id'] = $key->wrk_id;
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['daily_rate'] = $key->rate;
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['date'][$key->date]['work_hours'] = $key->reg_hour;
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['date'][$key->date]['adj_hour'] = $key->adj_hour;
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_ot'] += $key->ot_adj;
             $fetch[$key->wrk_id]['total_days'] += $key->reg_hour;
             
         }
         return $fetch;
     
    }
```

> Result of my Query

```
1: {total_ot: 1, total_days: 24, wrk_id: 1, daily_rate: 575,…}
daily_rate: 575
date: {2020-09-24: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0}, 2020-09-25: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0},…}
total_days: 24
total_ot: 1
wrk_id: 1
2: {total_ot: 0, total_days: 48, wrk_id: 2, daily_rate: 450,…}
daily_rate: 450
date: {2020-09-24: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0}, 2020-09-25: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0},…}
total_days: 48
total_ot: 0
wrk_id: 2
3: {total_ot: 0, total_days: 8, wrk_id: 3, daily_rate: 560,…}
daily_rate: 560
date: {2020-09-24: {work_hours: 8, adj_hour: 0}}
total_days: 8
total_ot: 0
wrk_id: 3
```

> In my vue... My formula is get the total of `work_hours` which is my
> `total_days` and `divide` it by `8` and `multiply` by `daily_rate` which
> is `daily_rate` is depend on the rate of per workers.. And I want to
> total it all

```
  <table class="table table-sm borderless">           
          <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr  v-for="fetch in assignmentTotal">
          <td style="height:10px;">Structural</td>
          <td style="height:10px;">{{(fetch.total_days / 8) * fetch.daily_rate)}</td>
          </tr>

          </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the sum on the PHP side and in Vue.js you only output the result.

```
$fetch = [];
$total_structural = 0;

foreach ($structural as $key) {
    // ...
    $total_structural += ($key->reg_hour / 8) * $key->rate;
}

$fetch['total_structural'] = $total_structural;

return $fetch;
```

Comment: Great! It Works :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use vuejs computed property

Call returnTotal() instead of  ({{(fetch.total_days / 8) * fetch.daily_rate)})

```
computed:{
returnTotal:function(){
var sum = this.assignmentTotal.reduce((acc,item)=> acc+ (item.total_days / 8) * item.daily_rate), 0);
  return sum;
}
}
```

Thanks